Can we generalize the Kuratowski Extension Theorem to Souslin spaces?
The Kuratowski Extension Theorem says: Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, $Y$ be a polish space, $A\subseteq X$, and $f:A\to Y$ be a measurable map. Then there is a measurable function $F:X\to Y$ such that $F|_A=f$.
A proof of the previous theorem can be found at the page 95 of the book "A Course on Borel Sets" written by SM Srivastava.
My quesiton is: Is the previous theorem also true if $Y$ is a Souslin space (i.e., Hausdorff space that is a continuous image of a Polish space)?
I'm asking this question because many theorems of that book can be generalized to Souslin spaces if we use the approach given in chapter 6 of the book "Measure Theory" written by VI Bogachev. However, I didn't find any strategy to generalize that theorem.
If you know any generalization of that theorem, please tell me.

This is going to be sensitive to how much you care about the extension being measurable with regards to $\mathcal{A}$ in particular rather than just measurable with regards to some natural completion of $\mathcal{A}$ (such as the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets in the relevant context).
First, let's see an example of it not working.

Example. There is a Polish space $X$, $A \subseteq X$, Souslin space $Y$, and Borel-measurable $f : A \to Y$ such that $f$ admits no Borel-measurable extension to all of $X$.

Proof. Let $X = [0,1]$ (with the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets), let $A \subseteq [0,1]$ be some non-Borel Souslin set, and let $f : A \to A$ be the identity map restricted to $A$. (So we are taking $Y = A$.) Assume that there is a Borel-measurable extension $F : [0,1] \to A$. We now have that $x \notin A$ if and only if $F(x) \neq x$, but $F(x) \neq x$ is a Borel condition (since it's the preimage of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ under the map $x \mapsto F(x) - x$), so this implies that $[0,1]\setminus A$ is Borel and therefore $A$ is Borel, which is a contradiction. $\square$

In a lot of applications though, the following proposition is probably sufficient.

Proposition. For any Polish space $X$, $A \subseteq X$, Souslin space $Y$, and Borel-measurable $f : A \to Y$, there is an extension $F : X \to Y$ that is $\sigma(\Sigma^1_1)$-measurable (i.e., measurable with regards to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by Souslin (a.k.a. analytic or $\Sigma^1_1$) subsets of $X$). In particular, $F$ is measurable with regards to the completion of any $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $X$.

Proof. First note that by Bogachev Theorem 6.7.4, we can find a Souslin set $Z \subseteq [0,1]$ and a Borel isomorphism $h : Y \to Z$.
Claim. There is a Souslin set $A' \subseteq X$ with $A' \supseteq A$ and a Borel-measurable function $g : A' \to Z$ extending $h \circ f$.
Proof of Claim. By the Kuratowski Extension Theorem, we can extend $h \circ f$ to a Borel-measurable $g_0 : X \to [0,1]$. Let $A' = g^{-1}_0(A)$. The Borel-measurable preimage of a Souslin set is Souslin, so we can take $g$ to be the restriction of $g_0$ to $A'$. $\square$
Now fix an arbitrary $b \in Z$ and define $G : X \to Z$ by
$$
G(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x) & x \in A' \\
b & x \notin A'
\end{cases}.
$$
For any open set $U \subseteq Z$, there is a Borel set $B \subseteq X$ such that either $G^{-1}(U) = B \cap A'$ (if $b \notin U)$ or $G^{-1}(U) = (B \cap A') \cup (X \setminus A')$ (if $b \in U$). In both cases, $G^{-1}(U)$ is a $\sigma(\Sigma^1_1)$ set. Therefore for every Borel $C \subseteq Z$, we have that $G^{-1}(C)$ is $\sigma(\Sigma^1_1)$.
Finally, we can take $F$ to be $h^{-1}\circ G$ and since $h$ is a Borel isomorphism, we have that $F^{-1}(D)$ is $\sigma(\Sigma^1_1)$ for any Borel $D \subseteq Y$. $\square$

Do you know of any reference that have this result? I want to cite it in my dissertation! Thank you very much!

@rfloc No I don't, sorry. Most of this is fairly standard. Universal measurability of $\Sigma^1_1$ sets is Lusin's famous result. It's Theorems 1.10.5 and 7.4.1 in Bogachev, for instance.

Then I will cite your answer in my dissertation. Thank you very much!
